# Keep one row of text for very similar "duplicates"

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

**Goal**: Keep one row for very similar "duplicates"

**Background**:
The `df` below shows that  `ID` `0` and `ID` `1` are "duplicates" of each other (`"hey there https://abc"` and `"hey there https://efg"` ). The text is nearly identical except for the `abc` and `efg` at the ends of each.

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ID=[1,2,3,4], Text=["hey there https://abc", "hey there https://efg", "hello", "hi"]))
```

**Output:**

```
    ID  Text
0   1   hey there https://abc
1   2   hey there https://efg
2   3   hello
3   4   hi
```

I can drop duplicates using the following code:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Text'], keep="first")
```

But since `ID` `1` and `ID` `2` aren't exact duplicates the code above will not work.

**Question**: How do I get the following output?

```
    ID Text
0   1   hey there https://abc
1   3   hello
2   4   hi
```

Comment: You'd first have to define 'duplicates'. You can use [`urllib.parse.urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) to parse website links, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you want to do but how about this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np                                      
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(ID=[1,2,3,4], Text=["hey there https://abc", "hey there https://efg", "hello", "hi"]))

df['idx']=df['Text'].str.contains('hey there https://')
first=np.where(df['idx']==True)[0][0] 
rep=df['Text'].values[first] 
df['Text'][df['idx']]=rep
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Text'], keep="first")
df.drop('idx',axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#convert column into list of strings
dfList = df['Text'].tolist()

output:
['hey there https://abc', 'hey there https://efg', 'hello', 'hi']


#split strings on https
split = [i.split('https:', 1)[0] for i in dfList]

output:
['hey there ', 'hey there ', 'hello', 'hi']



#put list back in df
df['Split_Text'] = split

output:

    ID  Text                    Split_Text
0   1   hey there https://abc   hey there
1   2   hey there https://efg   hey there
2   3   hello                   hello
3   4   hi                      hi


#keep one duplicate row
Nodup_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Split_Text'], keep="first")


output:
    ID  Text                    Split_Text
0   1   hey there https://abc   hey there
2   3   hello                   hello
3   4   hi                      hi


#eliminate Split_Text column
Nodup_df.iloc[:, 0:2]

output:

    ID  Text
0   1   hey there https://abc
2   3   hello
3   4   hi
```